# Select rows to columns in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table as shown below.

```
**id | location**
1  | East Flow
2  | East Level
3  | East Pressure
```

I would like to convert the above table as follows using select statement in Mysql.

```
1          | 2           | 3  
East Flow  | East Level  | East Pressure
```

I am using MySql 5.5
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression if the count of Id column is fixed or known.

**Query**

```
select max(case when id = 1 then location end) as `1`,
max(case when id = 2 then location end) as `2`,
max(case when id = 3 then location end) as `3`
from your_table;
```

If the count of `id` column is unknown then you may need to use dynamic sql.

**Query**

```
select
group_concat(distinct
    concat(
      'max(case when id = ',
      id,' then location end) as `', id,'`'
    )
  ) into @sql
from your_table;

set @sql = concat('select ', @sql, ' from your_table');

prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/855fd/1)

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. In my case the count of id column is unknown and not fixed. Any idea?

Comment: Hi, This solution is working. Thank you for that. But facing one more issue, when I run the dynamic SQL in MySql workbench it works perfectly, but when I run the same using eclipse Datasource explorer, I am getting syntax error. Any idea?